# How to hide an image if the progress bar reaches the value 0?

Tags: javascript, html

My Doffy img just won't hide and I don't know what to do.
I've been trying to add values and remove them and all, but it just won't work.

If anyone could help me I would highly appreciate it.

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="opdracht1.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=q, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Opdracht 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button id="pistol">Pistol attack (3 DMG)</button>
        <button id="bazooka">Bazooka attack (7 DMG)</button>
        <button id="katana">Katana attack (10 DMG)</button>
        <button id="punch">Punch attack (1 DMG)</button>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <img src="doffy.jpg" id="doffy">
    <p>Donquixote Doflamingo:</p>
    <progress min = 0 max=150 value=150 name=hel id=progress></progress>
    <script src="opdracht1.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    document.getElementById('progress').value-=3;
    console.log('You hit Doflamingo with your pistol attack. It caused 3 damage.');
  });

document.querySelector('#bazooka').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('progress').value-=7;
    console.log('You hit Doflamingo with your bazooka attack. It caused 7 damage.');
});

document.querySelector('#katana').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('progress').value-=150;
    console.log('You hit Doflamingo with your katana attack. It caused 10 damage.');
});

document.querySelector('#punch').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('progress').value-=1;
    console.log('You hit Doflamingo with your punch attack. It caused 1 damage.');
});

var progress = document.getElementById('progress') = 150;

if (progress = 0) {
    document.getElementById('doffy').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both syntax and logic issues.

I'll start with the beginning of the JS file, you wrote this:

```
    document.getElementById('progress').value-=3;
    console.log('You hit Doflamingo with your pistol attack. It caused 3 damage.');
  });
```

This is a syntax error and I believe you meant to write this:

```
document.querySelector('#pistol').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('progress').value-=3;
    console.log('You hit Doflamingo with your pistol attack. It caused 3 damage.');
});
```

Moving on to another syntax error:

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress') = 150;
```

You're already assigning a value to your variable 'progress', you can't assign another value to it, and besides it's the value of the progress element that you need to assign this value, since you already assign a default value in the HTML, there is no need to reassign that again, so maybe just this:

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
```

Now to the logic error, you're writing the following:

```
if (progress = 0) {
    document.getElementById('doffy').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Your JS file will be executed only once when the HTML is loading it, meaning that this code will run, check if the value of the progress is 0(which is obviously not, cause it's 150 by default) and that's it.

What you need to do here is monitor the value of the progress and perform your needed task there.

I'm not aware of onchange event listeners for progress value changes, so you might need to do that manually(if I'm wrong, please correct me!).

This could be done in the following way:

```
let changeEvent = new Event('change');
```

So let's start with monitoring the change of the progress element, this could be done like so:

```
progress.AddEventListener('change', function() {
    if (progress.value <= 0) {
        document.getElementById('doffy').style.display = 'none';
        console.log("doffy died.")
    }
});
```

Then each time we change a value we will need to also dispatch the change event:

```
document.querySelector('#bazooka').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('progress').value-=7;
    console.log('You hit Doflamingo with your bazooka attack. It caused 7 damage.');
    progress.dispatchEvent(chagenEvent);
});
```

So now we can monitor the value changes and we have no syntax errors, this should work, but we have some bad practices in our code, do you see how we repeat our lines over and over? Maybe we will declare the progress element at the beginning and use arrays and loops to improve that?

```
let progress = document.getElementById('progress');
let changeEvent = new Event('change');

let attacksInfo = [
    { "name": "pistol", "damage": 3 },
    { "name": "bazooka", "damage": 7 },
    { "name": "katana", "damage": 150 },
    { "name": "punch", "damage": 1 }
];

attacksInfo.forEach(weapon => {
    document.querySelector(`#${weapon.name}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
        progress.value -= weapon.damage;
        console.log(`You hit Doflamingo with your ${weapon.name} attack. It caused ${weapon.damage} damage.`);
        progress.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
    })
})

progress.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (progress.value <= 0) {
        document.getElementById('doffy').style.display = 'none';
        console.log("doffy died.")
    }
});
```

We used an array of JSON objects specified with the weapon name and damage, and then we iterate over the array and assigning the event listener to each weapon.

Maybe there are some more advanced concepts here which you haven't learned yet, let me know if there's anything that's not clear for you.